# Token based WebAPI theory from scratch

Tags: c#, .net, token, asp.net-web-api

I am interested in how token based authentication and authorization works. I am looking for a good article or rather group of articles (or book in the end) using which I finally reach enlightenment of how it works. I mean that I have found a huge number of examples and blog-posts about ASP .NET Identity, about Web API based on OWIN etc. But I couldn't find any explanation how it can be developed "from scratch": from database tables to appliction logic without any frameworks (includes EF) which wraps and hides all interesting things.

Thank you for your patience if you have read my question to the end.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/876870/Implement-OAuth-JSON-Web-Tokens-Authentication-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thank you everybody!
I want publish the answer for my question. In the end my researches showed me I didn't know what JWT is. It was the cause of my incomprehension. WebAPI implementing with ASP .NET Identity based on JWT (JSON Web Token). You can see an example of how it works [here](http://jwt.io/introduction/), or read about it fully [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). So, have a nice read and thank you everybody one more time, who helped me to find the truth.

I hope after these articles you'll understand all my questions and anger I felt before :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently implementing exactly what you are trying to learn, This is the most helpful articles I've found which helped me alot while creating the whole solution:

- [Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity)
- [AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)
- [Enable OAuth Refresh Tokens in AngularJS App using ASP .NET Web API 2, and Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/)

Comment: BitOfTech is a great resource for ASP.NET and token auth

Comment: I think you are implementing your system using EF and another Microsoft utils like asp .net Identity etc. But I wanted to avoid all this tools and look at token-based-system in painted models and text descriptions. But thank you for links, it is very useful.

Comment: @Jonesopolis and Mohammed ElSayed thanks for referring to my posts, happy to here that resources are useful for your projects :)

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukadc/archive/2012/05/24/claim-based-security-for-asp-net-web-apis-using-dotnetopenauth.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/876870/Implement-OAuth-JSON-Web-Tokens-Authentication-in

The above links might be useful